# facebook og:title not working, facebook scraper does not see anything

Tags: facebook, facebook-opengraph

This is my html:

```html
<html>
  <head>
    <meta property="og:title"   content="This is my title" />
    <meta property="og:description"  content="This is my content" />
  </head>

  <body>
    test
  </body>  
</html>
```

Now the facebook-debug-tool tells me that 'og:title' of type 'string' is not provided. Clicking on "See exactly what our scraper sees" returns a blank page. The "test" within the body is not displayed. I have already disabled gzip content type as it was proposed in another answer...

Comment: I see no errors in your code, perhaps adding more og like og:url and waiting a bit too. I use facebook open graph every day and it's always working like a charm. [open graph facebook markup](https://developers.facebook.com/docs/sharing/webmasters#markup)

Comment: It seems now as if facebook did not read any data from my server at all... entering a non existing path on my server renders a diffrent error-message though. Facebbok does reach my server, but does not get the thml of the file?

Answer (score 0):

The problem was that I had ReWrite-Rules in place that were originally targeted at the google-crawler. Long story short: The facebook-crawler got hooked by those Rewrite-Rules, too. After removing the rewrite rules everything worked like a chram.